# ruby-on-rails: revision counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I want to add a revision counter to my rails app.

Not the number of commits necessary but the number of live pushes/deployments for example.

I'm using github as my remote repo.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not one magic solution.
But basically, you should execute some code every time you deploy your application that increments the number of deployments by one.

One solution would be to create a capistrano task which would increment this.

```
namespace :deploy do
    desc "Increments the number of deployments"
    task :increment do
        Config.find_by_key('deployments').update('value = value + 1'
    end
end
```

It will take the uplet "deployments" in a config database (which you have to implement, this way or an other).

And in your capistrano recipes, you add the following :

```
after "deploy", "deploy:increment"
```

Every time you deploy your application, the deployment value in the config model will be updated by one.

This is only one example of a possible implementation. You might want to store the number of deployments somewhere else.
The main idea is to have the code executed every time you deploy.